# installing pygame in window8.1(64bit)

Tags: python, pygame, platform

I had tried
    "pip install wheel"
    "pip install --upgrade pip"

And both Successfully installed.

So, I tried..
    pip3.4.exe install "C:\Users\Myname\Downloads\pygame-1.9.2a0-cp34-none-win_amd64.whl"

This was what I got 
    pygame-1.9.2a0-cp34-none-win_amd64.whl is not supported wheel on this platform-

python version : 3.4
system type : 64-bit OS

I downloaded file from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pygame

Comment: You downloaded a 64-bit package, do you have a 64-bit python install?  (Just because you have a 64-bit OS, doesn't mean you have a 64-bit Python build.)  What is the header when you open the interactive interpreter?  It should start `Python 3.4...... on win32` -- fill in those dots for us.

Answer (score -1):

To fix this, try installing the 32 bit version of python and then try installing py3 version of pygame. download the pygame microsoft installer from [here](http://pygame.org/download.shtml).

Comment: This is not very good advice. On top of only having 32-bit builds, the official installers don't exist for Python 3.4 or even 3.3 (and downgrading from 3.4 to 3.2 is painful… I'd almost recommend going back to 2.7 instead if you can't have 3.3), they're old-fashioned installers that may not play well with other things installed via `pip`, and they're usually at least one bugfix version behind. Christoph Gohlke's site, where the OP got the unofficial binaries, doesn't have any of those problems, and it's usually the best place to get any Windows packages, if he has them.